# Get smarty variable into JavaScript

Tags: php, smarty

I want to make a simple snippet. I would like to console.log a smarty variable. I tried :

```
{php}
$GLOBALS['smarty']->assign("somevar", 'somevalue');
{/php}
```

And in my JavaScript

```
{literal}
<script>
{/literal}{$smarty.lbrace}{literal} 
var new_var = '{/literal}{$somevar|escape:javascript}{literal}';
{/literal}{$smarty.rbrace}{literal}
console.log(new_var)
</script>
{/literal}
```

It give me a blank page and nothing in the console log.
In log I get

> Smarty Error: Syntax error in template
>   "file:/usr/share/nginx/html/page.tpl"
>   on line 367 "{/literal}{$smarty.lbrace}{literal}" $smarty.lbrace is
>   not defined

I also tried

```
{literal}
<script>
var new_var = '{$somevar}';
console.log(new_var)
</script>
{/literal}
```

It output `{$somevar}`

And

```
{literal}
<script>
var new_var = '{/literal}{$somevar}{literal}';
console.log(new_var)
</script>
{/literal}
```

console.log return blank

Comment: The second won't work because it's considering `{$somevar}` as a literal too, that's why you need to stop the literal and restart it. The first one not working is weird tho. Could you add the full hierarchy and if you have anything else in your file?

Comment: This code is in the same file. I'm using it on whmcs

Comment: I fixed, it was a typo error, sorry about that ! But I still cannot log `new_var`

Comment: If you try to console.log("string test") does it show the result?

Comment: @Islam Yes I can output in console.log. It look like the new_var is empty but I don't know why

Comment: and if you var_dump the php value what do you get ?

Comment: @Islam well it return NULL with `{$somevar|@var_dump}`. So how can I assign it ?

Comment: I'm sorry I see no reason for it not to work, and I can't reproduce either ..

Comment: Thank you for debugging, I'm going to post a question about it

Comment: Could You please try `$smarty->assign('somevar', 'somevalue');` for assigning the var. Because I don't know if it is run in the right context within the php tags?

Comment: @ivion I tried it return me a blank page

Comment: What about `{assign var="somevar" value="somevalue"}`

Comment: @ivion I got the same issue but I need to assign with PHP

Comment: @Isam I found the issue I need to use `$template` instead of `$GLOBALS['smarty']`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, declare your smarty variable :

```
{assign var=somevar value="somevalue" scope="global"}
```

And, use it in your .tpl file who will contains your JavaScript in < script> tag :

```
<script>
var new_var = {$somevar}
console.log(new_var)
</script>
```

if you want to use a value from the PHP, you assign it to the smarty object, call the view, and display it with the same method.

Comment: He's not looking to assign a smarty object, he's looking to use a PHP assigned variable inside smarty. I'm not sure you really understood the question.